# How to do keyboard input using LÖVE?

Tags: input, lua, keyboard, love2d

When using LÖVE I want to change from one menu to another by hitting the ENTER key. But I only know `love.keypressed`, and `love.keyboard.isDown`.

For those two I need to hold the button down but I only want it to be pressed once. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the change code in `love.keyreleased()`

---

Something like this in `main.lua`

```
local changeMenu =false

function love.draw()
    if changeMenu then 
        -- do what you need to do
        changeMenu = false
    end
end

function love.keyreleased(key)
    if key=="return" or key=="kpenter" then
        changeMenu = true
    end 
end
```

Comment: But is it permanent? The others just changes it as long as the the key is actually pressed down.

Comment: The event will be called when the key is released. It doesn't take any notice of how long the key was pressed for. So it'll only get called once when you let go of the key.

Comment: Do you know how to call it from love.draw()? Sorry to be asking so many questions. I'm learning love. ;)

Comment: You can't. It's a top level function like love.draw(); you implement it in main.lua. Best approach is to update some kind of state variable in the keyreleased() function and act on it in love.draw().

Comment: How do I create that state variable? Do I just `changeMenu = love.keyreleased("enter")`

Comment: Seems like `changeMenu = love.keyreleased("enter")` gives me a stack overflow error.

Comment: Oh didn't notice the code you pasted up there. That worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to give me a bit more info. The code I posted will hit any code that replaces the comment exactly once each time enter is released. Did you add in your own code there? Can you post it?

Comment: After all this long time I've tried the thing again but it didn't work. Well seems like LOVE2D isn't my thing so yeah.